# Laravel form submission error

Tags: php, forms, laravel

I have a laravel blade template form like below.

```
<html>
<title>Blade Template Form</title>
<h2>Blade Form</h2>
{{Form::open(array('url'=>'form_ok'))}}
<p> 
{{Form::label('fname','First Name')}}
{{ Form::text('fname') }}
</p>
<p> 
{{Form::label('lname','Last Name')}}
{{ Form::text('lname') }}
</p>
<p> 
{{Form::label('username','User Name')}}
{{ Form::text('uname') }}
</p>
<p> 
{{Form::label('email','Email')}}
{{ Form::email('email') }}
</p>
<p> 
{{Form::label('male', 'Male')}}
{{ Form::radio('sex','Male') }}
{{Form::label('fmale', 'Female')}}
{{ Form::radio('sex','Female') }}
</p>

{{ Form::submit('Send Now') }}

{{ Form::close()}}

</html>
```

and my routes.php

```
Route::get('blade_form',array('as'=>'blade_form','uses'=>'Main@blade_forms'));
Route::get('form_ok',array('as'=>'form_valid','uses'=>'Main@form_success'));
```

i want to go the form after clicking submit button to 'form_ok' route.

my controller is below

```
public function form_success()
{
    return View::make('form_ok');
}
```

and the file form_ok.blade.php file have a success message.

normally the url is working fine in browser. but cant getting through form submission. please give a good solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a glance I can see you need to change your 'form_ok' route to post if that's the route your form "posts" to:

```
Route::post('form_ok',array('as'=>'form_valid','uses'=>'Main@form_success'));
```

Another thing you might need to change is `{{Form::open(array('url'=>'form_ok'))}}` to use your route name as "form_ok" is not a url. Check the [docs](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/html#opening-a-form) for more info on forms.